# Get object property value

Tags: javascript

This will not help. How get `obj` of the property sum?

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    value: 1
  },

  b: {
    value: 2
  },

  sum: {
    value: obj.a.value + obj.b.value
  }
};

console.log(obj.sum);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use in inline getter to code self-reflecting expressions in literals like that:

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    value: 1
  },

  b: {
    value: 2
  },

  get sum(){
    return this.a.value + this.b.value
  }
};

console.log(obj.sum); // shows: 3
```

this is ES5, but often over-looked. it works in all major browsers (even IE8) and node.

the getter syntax is nice because `obj.sum` both acts like a number and stays updated automatically as `a` and `b` change.

of course, it's probably more traditional to use a method (a function) and call it like `obj.sum()`, as that indicates to other coders that it's a "computed property" more or less...

Comment: Thanks guys. Thanks.

Comment: The **`get`** command acts as a shorthand for **[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)**. e.g. `Object.defineProperty(obj, "sum", { get: function() { return this.a.value + this.b.value; } });`

Answer (score 4):

`sum` itself is suppose to be a JavaScript function. So this is valid:

```
var obj = {
    a: {
        value: 1
    },

    b: {
        value: 2
    },

    get sumValue(){
        return this.a.value + this.b.value
    }
};
```

You can learn more about object methods [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp).

Comment: what is `value:` in sum()? seems a little confusing to label that expression for cosmetic reasons... it also doesn't return anything, so that won't work as shown...

Comment: @Dsafds, not working

Comment: The syntax of this object initializer is invalid.

Comment: This is incorrect initialization for an object method, I'm not sure why people are up voting this?

Comment: -1 What? initialize object properties, and then, after comma `this.sum` and the function not return anything, and also, have a object syntax? WTF IS THAT!!!

Comment: Oh sorry wrong syntax

Comment: Updated my code uptop

Comment: This is ES6 syntax, it [works fine](http://jsbin.com/kiweda/2/edit?js,output) in a sufficiently modern browser.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the object initializer, the object has not been assigned to the variable `obj` yet. Then, `obj` is undefined, so you can't use `obj.a.value`.

But you can achieve something similar by instantiating an anonymous function:

```
var obj = new function() {
  this.a = {
    value: 1
  };
  this.b = {
    value: 2
  };
  this.sum = {
    value: this.a.value + this.b.value
  };
};
```

Comment: this is a good example of an anon constructor. i think with `Object.assign` to cleanup the statics/reduce weight, this should be more popular of a pattern than we see out there. it's a good suggestion. of course there's a balance and this costs more than a literal, but i like the ability to init with arbitrary code...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to add a method to your Object, if so it should be like so:

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    value: 1
  },
  b: {
    value: 2
  },
  sum:function() {
    return this.a.value + this.b.value
  }
};

console.log(obj.sum); //Returns the function object
console.log(obj.sum()); //Returns the value 3
```